# Morphism, rational maps and their inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

I have two rather distinct questions on rational functions and rations maps:

1) Let $X$ be an affine variety (irreducible,  if necessarily) and $U \subset X$ -- a nonempty open set. $f \in K(X)$ -rational function, with $dom{f}=U$. Is it possible to find $g \in K[X]$ -- regular function on $X$ such that $f$ and $g$ coincides on $U$?

2) Let $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be dominant morphism of X, Y -- irreducible affine varieties. $\phi$ is injective on some open set $X_0$. It is said then that for existence of rational map $\rho: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $\rho\phi=1_{X}$ (everywhere where $\rho$ is defined) it is sufficient to have an inclusion $K[X] \hookrightarrow K(Y)$. So, my question is natural: why is it sufficient?

As I see, such inclusion $K[X] \hookrightarrow K(Y)$ (denote it by $\rho^*$) defines dominant rational map $\rho: Y \rightarrow X$. Since $\rho$ is defined on some open subset of $Y$, $\phi(X_0)$ contains principal open set of $Y$, and the fact that any two open subsets of irr. varieties intersect --  the composition $\rho\phi$ is well defined on some open subset $U$ of $X$ ($U \subset X_0$). The question is how to make $\rho\phi$ be identity there (why will it automatically be identity)?

Many thanks for any explanations!

**UPD:** The answer to the question 1) is affirmative iff $f$ is regular.

Comment: There must be something missing in 2), what about this example $X=Y=\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi(z)=z^2$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, thanks for comment

Comment: But do you agree with it ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, yes, your map is not bijective. You can claim the existence of inverse (rational) map only for bijective (injective) dominant morphism on some open subset

Comment: So injectivity on an open set is your hypothesis.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, It means that i missed it in my first version of question. It seems to be rather clear why injectivity is required here, even if you think of varieties in terms of sets

Comment: 1) Consider the map $t\in\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}\setminus\{0\}\to\frac{1}{t}\in\mathbb{K}$...

Comment: @Armandoj18eos, excuse me, but what exactly do you mean? Is it obvious ( not intuitively) that $f(t)=1/t$, $t \in \mathbb{K} \setminus \{0\}$  then $f(t)$ is not polynomial? By the way, your comment led me to see my question in some other, more general view. And the answer (to the part 1) is always "no", because since $X$ is irreducible any two rational functions that coincide on some open set are equal, thus if it is as in 1) then $f$ needs to be regular

Comment: @SashaMayer Yes all right! The answer to (1) is yes if and only if, without change the names from the original question, $f$ is regular on $X$! ^_^